# Why this harmonic sequence is not contractive

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm studing the contractive sequences and the Cauchy criterion for sequence convergence .
In an example from the book it's said that the sequence defined as $$  h_n:=(1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n)$$
it's divergent . But in my opinion it's respect the contrative theorem.
What's my mistake ?
Thanks

Comment: What is "contrative theorem"? (check spelling)

Answer (score 3):

If $h_n$ were indeed contractive, there would be some $c\in (0,1)$ such that for all $n\geq 1$, $|h_{n+2}-h_{n+1}|\leq c|h_{n+1}-h_{n}|$ which is the same as $\frac{1}{n+2}\leq c \frac{1}{n+1}$.

This would imply $\frac{n+1}{n+2}\leq c$, and letting $n$ go to $\infty$, $$1\leq c$$ a contradiction.